# Another way to make "always running application"?

Tags: android, operating-system, android-service

Just noticed that [Easy Controller-Control Center](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shere.easycontroller) application doesn't have foreground service, but never been closed by Android.

Does the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` make applications non-closable?

Comment: `Services` can make your application running  read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Services don't guarantee that application will run all the time. Moreover, using Foreground Services require notification, but Easy Controller-Control Center doesn't provide any notifications. It just running all the time.

Comment: May be you just keep your application running and don't call Activity.finish(); and also make it singleTask

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to that

**Approach # 1**

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
}
```

**Approach # 2**

Remove your key listener or return true when you have KEY_BACK

you just need the following to catch back key (make sure not to call super)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

Comment: AZ, the question is about application that don't use Foreground Service(no notification it the bar) and still works forever.